# Autocomplete no muestra datos en HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, autocompletar

Buen dia, espero me puedan apoyar con un error que me esta generando el autocomplete. Mi codigo esta en C# y ocupo webforms para la parte del html.

En esta parte esta lo que recibo en el controlador en el cual si me trae todo bien , los resultados de la busqueda y la información.

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult OBTENEPATENTE(string cvePatente)
        {
            List<Cliente> lstEmp = new List<Cliente>();
            using (ServiceClient ws = new ServiceClient())
            {
                Cliente[] ltblCvePatente = ws.SP_GETLISTAPATENTES(cvePatente);
                foreach (WSUSUARIOSSIIANET.Cliente val in ltblCvePatente)
                {
                    Cliente emp = new Cliente();
                    emp.cvePatente = val.cvePatente.ToString();
                    lstEmp.Add(emp);
                }
            }
            return Json(lstEmp); // Devuelve los datos como JSON
        }
```

En esta parte llamo  en el javascript la ruta del controller, mi etiqueta txt se encuentra dentro de un modal, al seleccionar deben aparecer las coincidencias con el número que se pone.

```
$('#modalCrear').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#txtCvePatenteAgregar").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var cvePatente = $("#txtCvePatenteAgregar").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: '../../Default/OBTENEPATENTE',
                        data: JSON.stringify({ cvePatente: cvePatente.trim() }),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.cvePatente, value: item.cvePatente };
                            }));
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("No Match" + JSON.stringify(result));
                        }
                    });
                },
                appendTo: "#modalCrear" // Aquí especificamos el contenedor de la ventana modal
            });
        });
```

Aqui se encuentra mi etiqueta esta se encuentra dentro del modal.

```
 <div class="modal animated bounce bd-example-modal-lg" id="modalCrear" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabe2" style="color: white; font-size: 16px">Creación de usuario</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-link text-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm" style="font-size: 12px">¿? Ayuda</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="txtAmaternoAgregar" class="col-form-label" style="color: white; font-size: 14px">Apellido Materno </label>
                                       
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label for="lbCvePatenteAgregar" runat="server" class="col-form-label" style="color: white; font-size: 14px">Clave patente</label>
                                        <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtCvePatenteAgregar" runat="server" Style="font-size: 13px;" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                                       
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Pero aqui esta el problema cuando le doy a la etiqueta donde busca las coincidencias si, encuentra información y despliega la información pero no dentro del modal, ni en la etiqueta si no, en una esquina de la  pantalla. Ya intente varias maneras de solucionar con css pero sigue apareciendo en la orilla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se muestra como me aparece el contenido. Espero alguien me pueda apoyar , como mencione ya intente con css con esta parte pero no realiza realmente lo que debe de hacer.

```
position: absolute;
        /*z-index: 2150000000 !important;*/
        cursor: default;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        padding-left: 100px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: red;
        z-index: 1100;
        width: 300px;
    }
```